# Using Mouseover to Send the user to a new page

Tags: javascript, image, hyperlink, mouseover

So, for an assignment I need to describe images to a user. The way the instructor wants it done, I need to use the "mouseover" javascript method to send the user to a page describing the image.

This is what I have so far, but I cannot get it to work.

```
<div class="image1"> 
<img id="solomid" src="Team_SoloMid.png" alt="Team Solomid Logo" style="width:300px;height:228px">
</div> 


<script type="text/javascript"> 
document.getElementbyId("solomid").addEventListener("mouseover", Mouseover); 

function Mouseover(){
window.location = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Team_SoloMid";
}
Mouseover();
</script>
```

Can anyone help me? I've a couple variation of this, but I can never get the mouseover to actually redirect the user to a page. 
And yes, the page is about League, writing programs about stuff I'm interested in helps break up the monotony.

Comment: Why are you immediately calling `Mouseover()`? Isn't that redirecting you as soon as the page loads?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`document.getElementbyId` Is not a function. The "b" in "by" must be capitalized. Also, remove the line `Mouseover();` so that users aren't immediately redirected.

Comment: Thank you! Sometimes you just need second pair of eyes for those sytax things.

Comment: Yeah I know what you mean. I found the error in the console, always remember to look there, and good luck with your project!

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this..

```
    <div class="image1">
        <img id="solomid" onMouseOver="document.location.href='https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Team_SoloMid'" src="Team_SoloMid.png" alt="Team Solomid Logo" style="width:300px;height:228px">
    </div>
```